# Splitting data into training/testing datasets in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, data-mining

Upon some research I found two functions in MATLAB to do the task:

- **[`cvpartition`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/stats/cvpartition.html)** function in the Statistics Toolbox
- **[`crossvalind`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html)** function in the Bioinformatics Toolbox

Now I've used the `cvpartition` to create n-fold cross validation subsets before, along with the `Dataset`/`Nominal` classes from the Statistics toolbox. So I'm just wondering what are the differences between the two and the pros/cons of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on [@Mr Fooz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371822/splitting-data-into-trainning-testing-datasets-in-matlab/1372934#1372934)

> They look to be pretty similar based on the official docs of cvpartition and crossvalind, but crossvalind looks slightly more flexible (it allows for leave M out for arbitrary M, whereas cvpartition only allows for leave 1 out).

... isn't it true that you can always simulate a leave-M-out using kfold cross validation with an appropriate k value (split data into k fold, test on one, train on all others, and do this for all folds and take average) since leave-one-out is a special case of kfold where k=number of observations?

Answer (score 3):

Amro, this is not directly an answer to your `cvpartition` vs `crossvalind` question, but there is a contribution at the Mathworks File Exchange called [MulticlassGentleAdaboosting](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22997-multiclass-gentleadaboosting)  by user Sebastian Paris that includes a nice set of functions for enumerating array indices for computing training, testing and validation sets for the following sampling and cross-validation strategies:

- Hold out
- Bootstrap
- K Cross-validation
- Leave One Out
- Stratified Cross Validation
- Balanced Stratified Cross Validation
- Stratified Hold out
- Stratified Boot Strap

For details, see the demo files included in the package, and more specifically the functions `sampling.m` and `sampling_set.m`.

Answer (score 1):

They look to be pretty similar based on the official docs of [cvpartition](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/index.html) and [crossvalind](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/bioinfo/index.html), but crossvalind looks slightly more flexible (it allows for leave M out for arbitrary M, whereas cvpartition only allows for leave 1 out).

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is not directly referring to the Neural network toolbox, but perhaps someone else might find this useful. To get your ANN input data seperated in to test/validation/train data, use the 'net.divideFcn' variable.

```
net.divideFcn = 'divideind';

net.divideParam.trainInd=1:94;  % The first 94 inputs are for training.
net.divideParam.valInd=1:94;    % The first 94 inputs are for validation.
net.divideParam.testInd=95:100; % The last 5 inputs are for testing the network.
```